# Reflective objects

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

im trying to recreate the boxes as in the image below [image: boxes]

Im tweaking with meshphong material and lights to make the colors similair, but what i don't know how to achieve is the glossy reflection of other objects in the scene. (You can see some of the boxes give a delicate reflection from the surroundings).

As far as i found i should be using environment maps but they dont reflect other objects in the scene dynamicaly just the skybox or other texture put in inside. Maybe some hints how to make a similair reflection?

Comment: environment maps DO reflect the environment dynamically. Take a look at http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_effects_anaglyph (remove the anaglyph effect). You will see that as the bubbles move in the environment so does the reflection of the environment on them.

Comment: by environment i ment other cubes, in these case bubbles, which are not reflected by each other. sorry for misunderstanding.  
In the image attached, you can notice cubes have some kind of glossy reflection of other cubes

Comment: You need to use dynamic environment maps. What you do is you render to a texture each frame, grab the image and apply it as an environment map to your objects. Two passes are required. You would need to use the WebGLRenderTarget renderer.

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2.html

Comment: @WestLangley thanks i know this example very well :) the only thing is there only on the sphere other elements are reflected. Im wondering if it is a correct attempt to create a cubecamera for every object and in each frame hide each object after another and update each envmap separately ?

Comment: I think you are just going to have to give it a try.

Comment: Here is a blog post that uses the same technique that the example that WestLangley posted. It may be helpful. Though it seems that doing it for all your objects will be expensive. http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/58910953451/dynamic-reflections-in-three-js